# How to generate the same value per ID (for 1000 IDs in total) with rnorm?

Tags: r, dataframe, rep

I want to create a `data.frame` which should contain a parameter value (body surface area, BSA). It should be generated in this `data.frame` using `rnorm()` for 1000 IDs. With

```
BSA<-data.frame(rep(rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 1.81, sd = 0.2)))
```

I can easily obtain those values for 1000 IDs. However, I want to have not only 1 but 36 observations per ID. How can I generate the same BSA value based on the above-mentioned mean and SD 36 times for one ID and performing this procedure for 1000 IDs in total?

Unfortunately,

```
data.frame(rep(rnorm(1, 1.81, 0.2), times=36),times = 1000))
```

does not work, of course.

EDIT: The output should look like this:

```
1.89
1.89
1.89
1.67
1.67
1.67
1.74
1.74
1.74
```

That would be three observations per ID in one column.

EDIT2:
The code could look like this:

```
BSA<-data.frame(c(rep(rnorm(1, 1.81, 0.2), times=36), rep(rnorm(1, 1.81, 0.2), times=36)))
```

This would generate the desired output for two IDs but it's not very feasible to perform this for 1000 IDs.

Comment: To confirm, you want to have a data.frame consisting of 1000 identical columns with 36 observations each?

Comment: I'm not sure, what your output should look like. If you want 1000 rows with each 36 columns containing a `rnorm(1, 1.81, 0.2)` variable, `as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000*36, mean=1.81, sd=0.2), ncol=36))` should get the job done. Otherwise: please give an example of your desired output (perhaps with just 3 instead of 36 observations).

Comment: Since I want to build a dataset later, it should only be one large "BSA" column with 36000 observations in total.

Comment: Dear Martin, thanks for your reply. I have edited my first post for clarification.

Comment: The code could look like this: `BSA<-data.frame(c(rep(rnorm(1, 1.81, 0.2), times=36), rep(rnorm(1, 1.81, 0.2), times=36)))`
This would generate the desired output for two IDs. How can I automatize this for 1000 IDs?

Comment: Simplest way to do this is `data.frame(ID = rep(rnorm(n,1.81,0.2), each=36))` where `n =1000`. To check whether this is same as your code. do, `set.seed(0);BSA<-data.frame(ID = c(rep(rnorm(1, 1.81, 0.2), times=36), rep(rnorm(1, 1.81, 0.2), times=36)))` and then `set.seed(0);data.frame(ID = rep(rnorm(n,1.81,0.2), each=36))` both should give you the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cbind` in principle, and draw one `rnorm` per each `"id"`.

```
n <- 36  ## 36 IDs
o <- 5  ## 5 observations (change to 1000 in your case)

set.seed(42)
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(1:n, function(i) 
  cbind(id=i, o=1:o, v=rnorm(1, 1.81, .2))))
res[1:15, ]
#    id o        v
# 1   1 1 2.084192
# 2   1 2 2.084192
# 3   1 3 2.084192
# 4   1 4 2.084192
# 5   1 5 2.084192
# 6   2 1 1.697060
# 7   2 2 1.697060
# 8   2 3 1.697060
# 9   2 4 1.697060
# 10  2 5 1.697060
# 11  3 1 1.882626
# 12  3 2 1.882626
# 13  3 3 1.882626
# 14  3 4 1.882626
# 15  3 5 1.882626
```

Or, if you want a vector, mix `rep` and `replicate`, then `c`oncatenate the result,

```
set.seed(42)
res2 <- do.call(c, replicate(n, rep(rnorm(1, 1.81, .2), o), simplify=F))
```

even simpler using the `each=` argument of `rep` (thanks to *@Onyambu*).

```
set.seed(42)
res2 <- rep(rnorm(o, 1.81, .2), each=n)

res2[1:15]
# [1] 2.084192 2.084192 2.084192 2.084192 2.084192 1.697060
# [7] 1.697060 1.697060 1.697060 1.697060 1.882626 1.882626
# [13] 1.882626 1.882626 1.882626
```

To get a data frame, just do `as.data.frame(res2)` of course, or something similar.

Comment: please note that `rep` takes each argument ie try. `set.seed(42); rep(rnorm(o,1.81,.2),each = n)`. You do not need to use `do.call` or even `replicate`

Comment: @Onyambu Yeah, I put that in the answer!

Comment: @Onyambu: Thanks for the insight, I totally forgot about `each`! I had to switch `o` and `n` for the proper result. Looks also great!

Comment: @asher. I actually knew `o` and `n` were interchanged. But had to change my comment the moment I noted that you accepted the answer